# Multi Level Json Array

Tags: javascript, php, json

I am trying to construct a multi level JSON array in PHP that I don't know if it is possible. It would look like this:

```
{0:Name [ {name:name, id:id, type:type}, {name:name, id:id, type:type} ], 2:Name [ {name:name, id:id, type:type}, {name:name, id:id, type:type} ]}
```

I am having trouble with the array logic.

```
$resultArray = array();
$id = $row['id'];
$resultArray[$id] = $row['name'];
```

How can I now associate the array of objects to that same Id, without using " = " because it will of course replace the Name?

```
$resultArray[$id] = arrayofobjects
```

I keep ending up with

JSON

```
0:Array
[0: Object
 1: Object...
```

Which is almost fine. I just want it to look like

```
0:Name
[0: Object
 1: Object...
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Please paste the complete code.

Comment: That example is not valid JSON.

Comment: How it's possible to have `Name` instead of `Array`? Isn't `Name` is string?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
$id = $row['id'];
$resultArray[$id] = $row['name'];
```

The array key/name that you're using here is the value of `$id`, which is probably an Array and not a string (key), so when PHP is converting the array to JSON it just does the default action and calls it `Array` because it is an array.

If you want a multdimensional array, do something like this:

```
$resultArray['id']['name']
```

Or if you find out that `$row['id']` is indeed returning an array and not a string, then you might need to do something like this:

```
$id = $row['id'][0];
$resultArray[$id] = $row['name'];
```

Comment: Note that in JavaScript (and certainly JSON) arrays have only numeric keys.